# A view I wrote has bugged handlers so I want to alter the query manually. How do I get the current view display?

Tags: views

The view handler for locations is broken when the locations are in field collections.

I need to rewrite the view query, replacing 3 joins with 2 other joins, for the query to work.

I don't want to mess with other displays of the view - how do I get the currently used display with `hook_views_query_alter()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know the machine name of the view then you can wrap your code in an if statement.

```
function hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query){
    if($view->name == 'name_of_view_to_alter'){
        //do stuff to the query
    }
}
```

hook_views_query_alter takes two arguments &$view and &$query. If you don't already know the machine name, of course install devel and use dsm($view) to find what you need. Also very helpful calling that on the $query variable as well. I just did something very similar.

Comment: I have and know the view name, but I need to know the display.

Comment: $view->set_display will also let you set the display to a particular display value http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/function/view%3A%3Aset_display/7  That inside your if statement should work. For the particular display you want to edit, are your filters overridden?

Comment: A few clickthroughs lead to `$view->current_display` - thanks